# Reading multiple files from Zip Link Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a zip file URL link with mutliple csv files.

How can I read the files individually in Pandas directly and not after downloading into local folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this as one example...

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from io import BytesIO
import urllib.request as urllib2
import pandas as pd

# get the zip file
url = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.example.com/aZipFileWithDifferentCSVFilesInIt.zip").read()
files = ZipFile(BytesIO(url))

# get the file names into a list; you could use this list for different things 
# and to get certain files etc.
listOfFilesNames = files.namelist()

# open a file from the list; in this case position 23.  This part could be a loop etc. 
# and if 'specificFileName' do something different etc.
myCSV = files.open(listOfFilesNames[23])

# create the dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(myCSV)

# check the output
print(df)
```